# Is the Plymouth Bootsplash able to function on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, plymouth

I've been searching high and low and I haven't been able to find anything regarding Plymouth working for BSD. I realize this is generally a Ubuntu/Debian package, but I believe I recall seeing an article of a FreeBSD upcoming feature list for version 10. Does anyone know if this is accurate and if so, how does one get this working?

I'd use the build in bootsplash function that FreeBSD offers, but the lack of support for anything other than 256 color bitmaps (and PCX, bin or ASCII formats) is incredibly limiting. Additionally, the VESA kernal module was acting up and throwing kernal panics. So I would preferably lean towards a package like Plymouth or a similar package that could actually support animation anyway if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to compile Plymouth on FreeBSD right now. It failed due to usage of Linux headers (epoll.h, specifically). That doesn't mean, of course, that Plymouth can't be ported, but there is definitely no ready solution yet.

Also, I had to pass `--without-udev`, as FreeBSD doesn't have it too. That said, I'm not sure how useful Plymouth would be if one would manage to compile it.